# Getting error: no match for operator <<, when using operator ++ concurrently

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload many operators for a class assignment and need to get the << and ++ operators working together. Below is a sample of the code I'm dealing with. Let me know if you have any ideas.

decaring generic template

```
template (class T)  
class Vector 
{  
    public: 

    class VectIter
    {
        friend class Vector;
        private:
            Vector<T> *v; // points to a vector object of type T
            int index;    // represents the subscript number of the vector's
            // array.
        public:
            VectIter(Vector<T>& x);
            T operator++();
            T operator++(int);
            T operator--();
            T operator--(int);
            T operator *();

            friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const VectIter& rhs)
            {
                out << (*rhs) <<endl;
                return out;
            }
    };

    Vector(int sz); 
    ~Vector();

    T & operator[](int i); 
    void ascending_sort();

    private:
        T *array;              // points to the first element of an array of T
        int size;
        void swap(T&, T&);
};
```

and here is where the error occurs in the main:

```
Vector<Mystring> y(3);
y[0] = "Bar";
y[1] = "Foo";
y[2] = "All";;

Vector<Mystring>::VectIter iters(y);

cout << "\n\nTesting Postfix --";
for (int i=0; i<3 ; i++)
    cout << endl << (iters++);
```

Here is a sample of the operators I'm using:

```
T Vector<T>::VectIter::operator ++()  
{  
    if(index == (*v).size)  
        index = 0;  
    else  
        index++;  
    return (*v).array[index];  
}

T Vector<T>::VectIter::operator ++(int post)  
{  
    post = index;  
    if(index == (*v).size)  
        index = 0;  
    else  
        index++;  
    return (*v).array[post];  
}
```

This code seems to work with int variables but when I change it to my custom class Mystring I get the error.

Comment: Your sample seems to be missing.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed and just added it.

Comment: So what does "for (int i=0; i<3 ; i++) { cout << endl << iters; iters++; } do?

Comment: Anyway hard to know without seeing the VectIter, operator++ implementations.

Comment: I updated above to show the implementation of a couple operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator `operator++` returns a `T` rather than an iterator, so your iterator's `operator<<` isn't getting called. Most likely `Mystring` doesn't have an `operator<<` declared/defined OR `Mystring`'s `operator<<` takes a non-const reference as its second parameter and can't accept the temporary returned from your `operator++`.

EDIT: Given your update to the OP (that it works with `int`) you almost certainly need to implement `operator<<` for your `Mystring` class.

Comment: Other than adding in templates, this is how the code was given to me for the classes and I would like to try to change that part as minimal as possible. I did however add the operator << because it is used in the main... Maybe there is a problem there.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I just added it and it is working now. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Also see the answer from Jerry Coffin explaining the typical usage of `++` and `--`. Your usage would be very confusing to people who are used to the usual semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...you've defined your iterators quite a bit differently than they're normally defined. An iterator (at least in C++) normally acts roughly like a pointer: when you increment it or decrement it, the result is an iterator, not whatever type the iterator refers to. You have to dereference the iterator to get the referred to type.

The error you're seeing looks like it stems from the fact that although you've *declared* the `++` and `--` operators, you haven't defined them -- so when you try to use them, your code won't compile/link any more.

Comment: I have updated the code above to show some operator implementation. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Mystring` class have a << operator defined? Your iterator will end up exposing a Mystring object, whose operator<<() would be called with an ostream; you might be getting this error because it is not defined.

Comment: Ah, no it does not define that. I will try that now.

Comment: Awesome!! That was it, I did not define the operator in the given Mystring class file. I hate it when profs leave out important stuff like that. Thanks for the help!! :))